# Google Webmaster Tools leverage caching

Tags: node.js, cache-control, google-search-console

I don't understand this feedback. I have already enabled 24 hrs caching for static resources. So why am I seeing the feedback? Is the caching too short?

[image: Screen dump from Web Master tools]

Headers for one of the affected resources:

```
Response headers
----------------
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public, max-age=86400
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2123
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Mon, 20 Apr 2015 23:51:45 GMT
ETag:W/"84b-3727224626"
Last-Modified:Mon, 20 Apr 2015 12:57:43 GMT

Request Headers
---------------
Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,da;q=0.6
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH:AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.3
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:xxxxxxx
DNT:1
Host:xxxxxxxxx
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http:xxxxxxxxxx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
```

This is how I set the cache in Node.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../', config.get('staticContentPath')), {
        maxAge: (60 * 60 * 24) * 1000 // 24 hrs x 1000 because Express middleware expects miliseconds and not seconds
    }));
```

Comment: Why *aren't* you caching forever? You should use a cache-busting strategy (i.e. change the filename). What I do is append the file mod time to the filename, and then use a rewrite rule in nginx to just ignore the mod time and serve the real file. If you're serving your node app behind nginx or apache you can do this too, it's probably faster to serve static files this way.

Comment: I'm not caching forever because my static content changes weekly (new site and lots of updates). So a 24 hrs cache is just fine. What I'm after is not a different caching strategy (nginx) but why Google Webmaster Tools are suggesting me to fix something that already seems to be fine.

Comment: Yes, that's why I left it as a comment. It was only a suggestion. One that I don't think it would hurt even if your site changes frequently. I posted an answer below. Sounds like your only two choices are to up the cache time to a week (which would suck if the cache-timer started the day before your weekly update), or you can cache-bust like I suggested and not worry about it.

Comment: BTW, you don't have to add nginx or apache if you aren't already using them, you could take the source of [static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js) and modify it slightly to meet your needs or use [send](https://github.com/pillarjs/send) directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your hypothesis is correct.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching) it says:

> This rule triggers when PageSpeed Insights detects that the response from your server does not include caching headers **or if the resources are specified to be cached for only a short time.**

And further down:

> We recommend a **minimum cache time of one week** and preferably up to one year for static assets, or assets that change infrequently. If you need precise control over when resources are invalidated we recommend using a URL fingerprinting or versioning technique - see [invalidating and updating cached responses](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#invalidating-and-updating-cached-responses) link above.

Comment: Well, one week it shall be then :-)